# Can’t connect to Windows 2008 R2 VPS server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-desktop-services

I’m running windows 10 on my computer, and I can’t connect to my Windows 2008 R2 VPS Server via remote desktop. I keep getting this error message.

[image]

However, I am connected to my server successfully using other computer that runs on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check in System Properties on the Remote tab for problems.

> [Open Windows Explorer > Right Click "This PC" > Click "Properties" >
>   Click "Advanced System Settings" > Click the "Remote" tab]

Check to make sure your Remote Desktop is set to "Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)." If that doesn't fix you up, trying the Network Level Authentication option instead could work, but I doubt it, since that is turning up the security level.

**[System Properties - Remote tab]**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeVdw.png]

Another option would be to check the users that have access. Hit "Select Users" on the same Remote tab in System Properties and make sure the users/groups you need are listed there. This is less likely, since you're able to connect from another device, but it's always worth looking at to be sure.